# XEmacs menubar is not enabled

Tags: emacs, cygwin

Using Windows 10 I installed Cygwin32 and all available emacs/xemacs packages.

When I start emacs now it works fine but for some reason the 'menu bar' with all items like 'File', 'Edit', 'Options' are not enabled.

Hence I can't use it. E.g. I want to enable the option copy/paste as C-c - C-v but since it's disabled I can't do it.

This is my version:

```
$ ./emacs-X11.exe --version
GNU Emacs 26.1
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GNU Emacs comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You may redistribute copies of GNU Emacs
under the terms of the GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file named COPYING.
```

My question: how could I enable this menu? Should I add some other Cygwin packages or etc?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please ignore my question.
I found that in my case I simply forgot to install XServer.
After installing it the issue disappeared